# Export large MySQL database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

We are having a database with approx size 5 GB and it contains 25000 tables. The database engine is InnoDB. We want to export/import it in a quick way.

Can you please help me to export db in less time.

I have tried it with mysqldump, PHPMyAdmin, workbench, Heidi SQL, but all these taking many hours to export the database.

```
mysqldump -h XXX -u ABC -p xyz | gzip > xyz.sql.gz

mysqldump -h XXX -u ABC -p xyz > xyz.sql
```

Comment: Is there any updates to this question? Please inform us with the actions you did in order to achieve the db export.